# Eclipse CDT intellisense

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I´m using Eclipse CDT to develop on PIC32. I just use the IDE to do the programming and desktop debug (cygwin, when he wants to work).

I need help to improve Eclipse CDT auto complete (e.g. header files names, global variables, header file methods). Performance here it's not a major problem, it could be even a geany-like auto complete (where the symbols available are the ones that appears on the IDE open .c and .h, even if my .c can't reach that file).

Tks

Answer (score 0):

Are all your .c and .h files added to the cdt project?
Which Elipse/cdt version do you use?

Also, see http://sourceforge.net/projects/piccbuilder/
I have no experience in this plugin, it may or may not help you.